# Why can't I index a `[u32]` with a `u32`?

Tags: rust, vector, slice

What am I doing wrong with the variable `i` below? Why does the compiler say I cannot index a `Vec` with a `u32` and how do I fix it?

```
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let number: u32 = 4;
    let mut count = 0;
    
    for i in 0..number {
        if a[i] % 2 != 0 {
            count += 1;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    println!("{}", count);
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the type `[u32]` cannot be indexed by `u32`
 --> src/main.rs:7:12
  |
7 |         if a[i] % 2 != 0 {
  |            ^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
  |
  = help: the trait `SliceIndex<[u32]>` is not implemented for `u32`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Index<u32>` for `Vec<u32>`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=71cd8ae9bd8f97c4786be18208bfb2a7)

Answer (score 22):

Indexing is made possible by [Index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) and [IndexMut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) traits.

You are using a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) and it implements [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Index%3CI%3E) and [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IndexMut%3CI%3E) traits.

Although, it imposes a trait bound that type used to index should implement `SliceIndex<[T]>`:

```rust
impl<T, I> Index<I> for Vec<T>
where
    I: SliceIndex<[T]>
```

[`SliceIndex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html) is implemented for [`usize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html#impl-SliceIndex%3C%5BT%5D%3E) because of which it is possible to use type `usize` as index.

It is not implmented for `u32` because of which you can't use `u32` as index.

`i` has a type `u32` because it is received from the range `0..number` where `number` has type `u32`.

---

A simple fix would be to cast `i` to `usize`:

```rust
if a[i as usize] % 2 != 0
```

This cast can be safely done as long as you are on at least a `32` bit machine.

As per the [definition of usize](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html):

> The size of this primitive is how many bytes it takes to reference any location in memory

---

Moreover, your code doesn't require you to use `u32`. Instead you should use `usize` from the start.

Answer (score 7):

Quick remark: instead of changing the type of `number` to `usize` forever or constantly casting `i` to `usize` one may use the following construction which casts `number` to `usize` for the purposes of the `for` loop only:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let number: u32 = 4;
    let mut count = 0;

    for i in 0..number as usize {
        if a[i] % 2 != 0 {
            count += 1;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    println!("{}", count);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the type of `number` to `usize`, so the range `for i in 0..number` will also iterate over `usize`s. Indexing is typically done with `usize`